# BibLaTeX. Add postfix to label

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I need to have two types of bibliographies in my master thesis.
The first one contains my personal publications and need to have "—A" suffix in labels. Another contains other references and has numeric labels.

The problem is that I can't find how to add postix to labels.

[image: references in text]
[image: Bibliography with "-A" postfix]
[image: Simple bibliorgaphy]

Comment: Try creating custom labels with arguments. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262923/213149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex`'s `numeric` styles have the concept of a `labelprefix`. Unfortunately for us, `labelprefix` is a ... well ... prefix, so it is displayed before the label number. So we could easily get

> [A-1]

but not so easily

> [1-A]

Your image looks like you are using `gost-numeric`, which is based on `numeric-comp`. `numeric-comp` is one of the most complex `biblatex` standard styles, so quite a bit of code is needed to turn the `labelprefix` into a suffix.

Note that the modifications to the `numeri-comp` citation style will cease to work in future versions of `biblatex` (see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/900, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/963).

```
\documentclass[russian]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=gost-numeric, defernumbers, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelprefix}{--#1}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelnumber}%
        \printfield{labelprefix}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:comp:end}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntb}}{-1}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \printfield{labelprefix}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:comp:inset}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcntb}}{-1}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{entrysetcount}}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcntb}{-1}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:dump}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcnta}}{0}
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{cbx@tempcnta}}{1}
       {\bibrangedash}
       {\multicitedelim}%
     \bibhyperref[\cbx@lastkey]{%
       \printtext[labelnumber]{\cbx@lastnumber}%
       \ifdef\cbx@lastprefix
         {\printtext[labelprefix]{\cbx@lastprefix}}
         {}}}
    {}%
  \setcounter{cbx@tempcnta}{0}%
  \global\undef\cbx@lastprefix}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{worman,geer,nussbaum}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[resetnumbers, heading=subbibliography, type=article]
\newrefcontext
\printbibliography[resetnumbers, heading=subbibliography, nottype=article]
\end{document}
```

[image: 1-A]

---

From `biblatex` 3.15 onwards (not yet released, but `dev` versions are available on GitHub and Sourceforge), replace the block between `\makeatletter...\makeatother` with

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:print:labelnumber}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \printfield{labelprefix}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:print:subentry:full}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{entrysetcount}}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:print:last:labelnumber}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref:lastkey]{%
    \printtext[labelnumber]{\cbx@lastnumber}%
    \ifdef\cbx@lastprefix
      {\printtext[labelprefix]{\cbx@lastprefix}}
      {}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. Worked for me on texlive-full 2019.

Comment: +1: Remark: `https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issue/900` leads to an error 404 page (at least for me). Maybe there is a `s` missing in `issue(s)`.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner So it is. Fixed. Thank you very much.